# output jquery UI slider to mysql cannot get PHP file to pick up the POST data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Before I get started I must say, utter noob to coding and trying to learn, I am using JQuery UI Slider, I need to pass resultant data to a php file to update a mysql database,  but I am hitting a brick wall
here is the slider code

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 18,
  min: 15,
  max: 23,
  step: 0.1,

  slide: function( event, ui ) {

    // While sliding, update the value in the #amount div element
    $( "#amount" ).html( ui.value );

  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
        //alert(ui.value);
            $sliderValue=ui.value; //set the value to a global variable
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "temperature.php",
                data:"temp="+$ ( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ),
                success:function(response){
                alert(data);                    }
            });
        }
});
```

this works fine I can see the form value as the slider value being passed to temperature.php. 
So to test the PHP I am accessing the PHP file directly using .../temperature.php?temp=6
I can again see this (using chrome developer tools) as form data temp: 6 or source temp=6.

So finally the actual problem 
temperature.php

```
<?php
$temp= $_POST['temp'];
echo $temp;
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

$dbc = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET temp1='$temp',  WHERE id= "3"";

?>
```

this returns internal server error when accessing using .../temperature.php?temp=6

I have tried using GET and get the same problem,
probably something stupid so I apologise in advance. I hope someone can at least point me in the right direction, thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I thought I would update my post as much as it makes me feel like an idiot, the code was not at fault, it was actually an issue with chrome, having tried in different browser this then functioned as I expected and then having restarted chrome it worked fine in this too,  it was what I call a PICNIC error,  Problem In Chair Not In Computer, apologies if I wasted anyones time.